# What to put in start_application() to deploy to AppHarbor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, appharbor

I am trying trying to deploy a very simple asp.net MVC5 application to AppHarbor and the any page that requires a DB query produces the following error:

`Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'.`

Referencing what this guy has to say:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCXWVHwHVqk

I added the following to my `start_appliation()` method in the Global.asax.cs file:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(
     new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

This rewarded me with a new error:

`Migrations is enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext' but the database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create the database and its tables, for example by running the 'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.`

This is the connection string in my web.config file:

In the AppHarbor dashboard I set the connection string alias to "DefaultConnection" as well.

What on earth should I be putting in the start_application() method?  Or is there something else completely screwed up?

Comment: What database are you trying to connect to? What is your connection string?

Comment: Updated my question.  I'm just using the basic free shared SQL server add-on